# randomizing number again if statement was false JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

```
function computerLogic(array) {

    function random() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        if ((array[rand] === playerChoice) || (array[rand] === computerChoice)) {
            random(); < ----------------------- THATS MY PROBLEM,
        } else if (array[rand] === 0) {
            array[rand] = computerChoice;
            grid.item(rand).innerHTML = computerChoice;
        } else {
            alert("END OF THE GAME!");
            console.log(array[rand]);
        }
    }
    random();

}
```

so its part of my Tic Tac Toe code to put O or X to the grid.
This function is being called in function handling clicks of users.Every time user clicks something then this function is called and updated array is send to it.

Im recursively calling function random() to random again number if it is in range of if statement.

I dont want to call it recursively but I have no idea how to make var rand to random again instead of calling whole random() function again.

just ignore last else statement.

here you can look at all code if its chaotic for you. 
https://github.com/uRTLy/Tic-Tac-Toe

EDIT

```
function computerLogic(array) {

 function random() {

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);



var result = (array[rand] === computerChoice) || (array[rand] === playerChoice) ?
  random(): (function(rand) {
    array[rand] = computerChoice;
    grid.item(rand).innerHTML = computerChoice;
  })(rand);
}

random();


 }
```

done it like this also but still exceeds stack size and still does the same as earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while statement instead

```
while((array[rand] === playerChoice)||(array[rand] === computerChoice)) {    
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about it but how does it check the first If statement again ??
edit
You want me to put that inside of if statement or instead of if statement?

Comment: It now just randoms a number and not updates the board.

Comment: You need to move your if else statement into the while loop (below `rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);`). If `(array[rand] === playerChoice)||(array[rand] === computerChoice)` then say `return;`. This will exit the if statement and will return to the top where `rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);` will be called again. Inside the else if and else add `break;` to the end and this will exit the while loop.

Comment: while ((array[rand] === playerChoice) || (array[rand] ===        computerChoice)) 
   
I did it this way but I feel that my while statement is failing.

Comment: If array[random] is not equal computerChoice nor playerChoice the while loop wont execute so its wrong idea or i dont understand it.

Comment: You have to figure out how to implement it, it would take a great amount of time to download your code and test it. You will need use a while loop though.

Comment: `function computerLogic(array) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  var zero = 0;
  do {
  (function(random) {
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
      return random;
    })(random);
  } while (array[random] === zero);

  console.log(random);

  if (array[random] === zero) {
    array[random] = computerChoice;
    grid.item(random).innerHTML = computerChoice;
  }

}`

   look at that, I did as you said but still nothing going good.

Comment: just copy out to see normalized. Its not updating my view.